# Altering value of DomDocument element/node

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, dom-node

I'm building an XML like:

```
<?xml ... ?>
<root>
    <elements>0</elements>
    <list>
        <element>test1</element>
        <element>test1</element>
        <element>test1</element>
    </list>
</root>
```

After appending all `<element>`s, I want to replace `<elements>0</elements>` by `<elements>3</elements>` for example.

I tried `DOMNode::replaceChild`, but it has no affect.

```
$numberOfElements = $xml->createElement('numberOfElements', '0');
$root->appendChild($numberOfElements);

/* append elements and count them */

$root->replaceChild($numberOfElements,
                    $xml->createElement('numberOfElements', $countElements)
               );
```

How to properly use replaceChild or is there a different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php):

> `public DOMNode replaceChild ( DOMNode $newnode , DOMNode $oldnode )`

This means that you must specify the new node first, then the node to be replaced. You have it the wrong way around.

EDIT: That said, why not do this?

```
$numberOfElements->nodeValue = $countElements;
```

Comment: Dang! I'm used to work vice versa,.. like `str_replace(old, new, str)`.. Thanks! I will also try your suggest to directly write to the member ++

Comment: It seems like the DOMDocument class was closely based on JavaScript's DOM manipulation. In JS, it'd be `container.replaceChild(newNode, oldNode)`.